# how to display/hide html block code to php if variable is greater than zero

Tags: php, parsing

i would like to ask help in re-creating the code below. Im transferring form data from page1.php going to page2.php with the form datas from page1.php. The scenario is whenever the variable ddList1 is greater than 0 it will execute the code below displaying it in the html. otherwise when the variable is set to 0 it will hide the chunk of the html codes

```
    <?php
        if($_POST["ddList1"] > 0)
         echo $_POST["ddList1"];
    ?>
<table>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $_POST["ddList1"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $_POST["ddList1name"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $_POST["ddList1desc"]; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                                $_ddList1 = $_POST["ddList1"];
                                switch ($_ddList1) {
                                    case "1":
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                                        break;
                                    case "2":
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                                        break;
                                    case "3":
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>";

                                        break;
                                    case "4":
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>";
                                        break;
                                    case "5":
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>";
                                        break;  
                                    default:
                                        echo "out of range";
                                }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does the current code do?

Comment: how about some `{}` for the if?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <?php
    if($_POST["ddList1"] > 0){ ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $_POST["ddList1"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $_POST["ddList1name"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $_POST["ddList1desc"]; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php
                    switch ($_POST["ddList1"]) {
                        case "1":
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                        break;
                        case "2":
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                        break;
                        case "3":
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>";

                        break;
                        case "4":
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>";
                        break;
                        case "5":
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>&nbsp;";
                        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info ButtonOne1\" onclick=\"openwindow1();\" aria-label=\"Left Align\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>";
                        break;  
                        default:
                        echo "out of range";
                    }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement will run the statement echo $_POST["ddList1"]; since if follows this format.

```
if(expression) 
 statement;
```

since the "echo $_POST["ddList1"];" is the following statement, the conditional will only apply to this statement.

You might want to try this format:

```
<?php 

 if(condition): 
 statement1;
 statement2;
 ...
 ?>
 <h1>HTML code here!<h1>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ($_POST['ddList1']): ?>
<!--Nothing between if and endif will be executed if $_POST['ddList1'] is zero-->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $_POST["ddList1"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $_POST["ddList1name"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $_POST["ddList1desc"]; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php
                if ($_POST['ddList1'] > 5) {
                    echo "out of range";
                } else {
                    // It looks like all the buttons are the same, so you should 
                    // be able to simplify all the repeated code in the switch
                    $button = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info ButtonOne1" onclick="openwindow1();" aria-label="Left Align"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>&nbsp;';

                    // This will repeat the button HTML (ddList1) times
                    echo str_repeat($button, $_POST['ddList1']);
                }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, i tried the simplified code you posted however, the buttons are not displaying.

Comment: Hi @nhoyti Oops, I forgot something important. `str_repeat` just makes a string, it doesn't output it. Updated the answer with an `echo`. Sorry about that.